# Tunneling between two servers

Tags: vpn, centos7, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

There are two servers in this network
The first server benefits from censored internet
The second server uses uncensored internet
The client can only connect to the first server and connect to the first server via the outline.
My intention is to tunnel from server to server in order to eliminate censorship. How do I tunnel the first server to the second one?
Both servers use centos..
Prefer simple, high-speed methods like ssh tunneling and so on
Please guide me with full description

[This image can help you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSzch.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [gost](https://github.com/ginuerzh/gost/blob/master/README_en.md) to forward traffic from First Server to Second one.
For example in first server you can listen on Shadowsocks (ss) and Forward the traffic via sock5 to the second server. Then in the second server you should listen on sock5.

For example: 
In First Server:

```
gost -L=ss://chacha20:password@:8338 -F=socks5://server_ip:1080
```

In Second Server:

```
gost -L=socks5://server_ip:1080
```

Gost supports many protocols. You may check the various protocols to find proper protocol that overcome censored network.